# Android TableView or ListView

Tags: android, list, view

Hi,
I want to recreate the iOS TableView with sectioned headers in Android. I have tried a lot of things with section adapters in ListView, but I can't seem to get it work.
Can I do this in a scrollable TableView?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a listview.

See if this links help you:

[ListView with Sections/Separators](http://bartinger.at/listview-with-sectionsseparators/)

[ListView Tips & Tricks #2: Sectioning your ListView](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=440)